# How avoid use global variable in simple Slot Machine program

Tags: c++

This is my simple slot machine program and I just won a know how do not use the **global variable**? If someone helps me to clarify the subject, because my task book offered to use  the function, but try do not use **global variable** in that particular case.

My code:

```
int wheel1, wheel2, wheel3;

bool triple_equals(){

    if ((wheel1 == wheel2) && (wheel2 == wheel3)){
        cout << "Jack Pot!!! "; cout << "You Win!!! ";
    }else{
        cout << "You Loose your moneys!!!\n";
    }
}

int main(){

    cout << "Wheel 1: \n";
    cin >> wheel1;
    cout << "Wheel 2: \n";
    cin >> wheel2;
    cout << "Wheel 3: \n";
    cin >> wheel3;

    srand(time(0));
    wheel1 = rand() % 2 + 1;
    wheel2 = rand() % 2 + 1;
    wheel3 = rand() % 2 + 1;

    cout << "Result Wheel 1: " << wheel1 << "\n";
    cout << "Result Wheel 2: " << wheel2 << "\n";
    cout << "Result Wheel 3: " << wheel3 << "\n\n";

    triple_equals();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Two words: function parameters

Comment: Just declare them local in main() and pass by reference to every function.(or you might as well pass by value since they are just integers)

Comment: Its a C++ program not a C Program so why not use a class?

Comment: Why do you first ask the user for values for the wheel, but then immediately overwrite them with random values?

Comment: Guys, I just started study C++  a couple month ego and I wasn't able to use the Classes or answer why I first ask the user for values for the wheel...  I really appreciate your comments it's all very useful for the novice.

Answer (score 1):

Use function arguments:

```
bool triple_equals(const int wheel1,const int wheel2,const int wheel3){

    if ((wheel1 == wheel2) && (wheel2 == wheel3)){
        cout << "Jack Pot!!! "; cout << "You Win!!! ";
    }else{
        cout << "You Loose your moneys!!!\n";
    }
}

int main(){
    int wheel1, wheel2, wheel3;
    cout << "Wheel 1: \n";
    cin >> wheel1;
    cout << "Wheel 2: \n";
    cin >> wheel2;
    cout << "Wheel 3: \n";
    cin >> wheel3;

    srand(time(0));
    wheel1 = rand() % 2 + 1;
    wheel2 = rand() % 2 + 1;
    wheel3 = rand() % 2 + 1;

    cout << "Result Wheel 1: " << wheel1 << "\n";
    cout << "Result Wheel 2: " << wheel2 << "\n";
    cout << "Result Wheel 3: " << wheel3 << "\n\n";

    triple_equals(wheel1,wheel2,wheel3);

    return 0;
}
```